# Unable to connect to SQL Server with pyodbc on mac os

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, macos, pyodbc, macos-catalina

I have a remote SQL Server database which I'm trying to connect from localhost (Mac OS).

I've already installed 'Microsoft ODBC driver 17 for SQL Server':

```
brew tap microsoft/mssql-release https://github.com/Microsoft/homebrew-mssql-release
brew update
HOMEBREW_NO_ENV_FILTERING=1 ACCEPT_EULA=Y brew install msodbcsql17 mssql-tools
```

Then verified installed drivers:

```
>>> import pyodbc
>>> pyodbc.drivers()
['ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server']
```

odbcinst.ini:

```
[ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Driver=/usr/local/lib/libmsodbcsql.17.dylib
UsageCount=1
```

connection with pyodbc:

```
# I made a ssh tunnel, so the server is localhost with default 1433 port. 
dsn = 'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=localhost;Database=MyDB;UID=MyUser;PWD=MyPass'
pyodbc.connect(dsn, autocommit=False)

# The following error appears:
pyodbc.OperationalError: ('HYT00', '[HYT00] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

Also, I tested the connection with T-SQL and everything is fine:

```
% tsql -H localhost -U MyUser -P MyPass -p 1433
locale is "C/UTF-8/C/C/C/C"
locale charset is "UTF-8"
using default charset "UTF-8"
1>
```

Any ideas what's wrong with my setup?

Comment: Can you test without the SSH tunnel?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft, unfortunately, no, the database is behind a firewall, that's why I use the tunnel. But, everything works fine on our test server (Linux) which is in the same network as the database. I suppose the issue is in driver configuration on Mac OS. Also tested the connection in DataGrip (Microsoft JDBC Driver 8.2 for SQL Server (ver. 8.2.2.0, JDBC4.2)) and it works well on localhost:1433 with the running tunnel.

Comment: Was this ever resolved? I am having similar issues on Mac ARM